# SwiperJS styling does not work with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I've installed `SwiperJS` into my `NextJS` project. I've following exactly the Swiper Tutorial Documentation but there's an issue when I try to styling classes like `.swiper`, `.swiper-slide` ... The styles are not responding to my custom styles.

In my case, my slider is a Component and there is a folder called `Slider` with `index.tsx` file and `slider.module.scss`.

My index.tsx:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar } from 'swiper';

import styles from './slider.module.scss'

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

export function SliderPortfolio() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.teste}>
      <Swiper
        className={styles.mySwiper}
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={3}
        navigation
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className={styles.imageContainerNext}>
            <Image
              className={styles.imageNext}
              src={'/images/dribble-mockup.png'}
              alt="Illustration of a person carrying ideas for a professional website design"
              layout="fill"
            />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className={styles.imageContainerNext}>
            <Image
              className={styles.imageNext}
              src={'/images/dribble-mockup.png'}
              alt="Illustration of a person carrying ideas for a professional website design"
              layout="fill"
            />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className={styles.imageContainerNext}>
            <Image
              className={styles.imageNext}
              src={'/images/dribble-mockup.png'}
              alt="Illustration of a person carrying ideas for a professional website design"
              layout="fill"
            />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className={styles.imageContainerNext}>
            <Image
              className={styles.imageNext}
              src={'/images/dribble-mockup.png'}
              alt="Illustration of a person carrying ideas for a professional website design"
              layout="fill"
            />
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>

    </div>

  )
}
```

My slider.module.scss:

```
.teste {
  background:  blue; //works

  .mySwiper {
    background: red; //works

    .swiper {
      background: yellow; // doesn't work
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      display: none; // doesn't work
    }

  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved. I inserted the swiper styles classes at my main styles `global.scss` and worked. Thank you guys!

Comment: then what if you want to make dynamic style changes? I'm also looking for a way to do that

Comment: While this solves your problem, it can create issues if you need another slider with different styles.

Swiper.js allows custom class names on it's components (Swiper and SwiperSlider), so you can apply your *.module.(s)css classes there, it will keep them scoped to only that slider. 

This should allow for dynamic style changes too.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it is solved by changing

```css
import "swiper/css";
```

to

```css
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. It's working on `npm run dev` but not after getting static build `next build && next export`. I'm using Next.js 13 with Page Routing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't... Just because of this problem I don't use Next.js anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the css class names are correct, change the order of your imports

```
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

import styles from './slider.module.scss'
```

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Your webpack configuration could be changing the resulting class names, can you add it into your question(if its Nextjs default its not needed)? Or try changing the name from .module.scss to .scss(and import as `import './slider.scss')`, but it would depend on your config

Answer (score 0):

```js
it work in yarn dev but when i make build it do not work
import 'swiper/css'; // also tried import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
export { Navigation, Thumbs, Pagination, Autoplay, Grid } from 'swiper';
export { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
export type { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper';


import {
  Navigation,
  Swiper,
  SwiperOptions,
  SwiperSlide,
  Thumbs,
} from '@/components/ui/carousel/Sliders'
import { productGalleryPlaceholder } from '@/public/assets/placeholders'
import { getDirection } from '@/utils/getDirection'
import cn from 'classnames'
import { Attachment } from 'lib/types/products'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { IoIosArrowBack, IoIosArrowForward } from 'react-icons/io'
import Scrollbar from '../Scrollbar'

interface Props {
  gallery: Attachment[]
  thumbnailClassName?: string
  galleryClassName?: string
}

// product gallery breakpoints
const galleryCarouselBreakpoints = {
  '0': {
    slidesPerView: 4,
  },
}

const swiperParams: SwiperOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
}

const ThumbnailCarousel: React.FC<Props> = ({
  gallery,
  thumbnailClassName = 'xl:w-[480px] 2xl:w-[650px]',
  // galleryClassName = 'xl:w-28 2xl:w-[130px]',
  galleryClassName,
}) => {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<any>(null)
  const prevRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const nextRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  const dir = getDirection(locale)

  return (
    <div className="w-full xl:flex xl:flex-row-reverse">
      <div
        className={cn(
          'relative mb-2.5 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border border-border-base md:mb-3 xl:ltr:ml-5 xl:rtl:mr-5',
          thumbnailClassName
        )}
      >
        {!!thumbsSwiper ? (
          <Swiper
            id="productGallery"
            thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: prevRef.current!, // Assert non-null
              nextEl: nextRef.current!, // Assert non-null
            }}
            {...swiperParams}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.original ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product gallery ${item.id}`}
                  // width={650}
                  // height={590}
                  width={540}
                  height={440}
                  className="rounded-lg object-contain"
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        ) : (
          <Swiper
            id="productGallery"
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            navigation={{
              prevEl: prevRef.current!, // Assert non-null
              nextEl: nextRef.current!, // Assert non-null
            }}
            {...swiperParams}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.original ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product gallery ${item.id}`}
                  width={540}
                  height={440}
                  className="rounded-lg object-contain"
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        )}
        <div className="absolute top-2/4 z-10 flex w-full items-center justify-between px-2.5">
          <div
            ref={prevRef}
            className="flex h-7 w-7 -translate-y-1/2 transform cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-brand-light text-base shadow-navigation transition duration-300 hover:bg-brand hover:text-brand-light focus:outline-none md:h-8 md:w-8 lg:h-9 lg:w-9 lg:text-lg xl:h-10 xl:w-10 xl:text-xl"
          >
            {dir === 'rtl' ? <IoIosArrowForward /> : <IoIosArrowBack />}
          </div>
          <div
            ref={nextRef}
            className="flex h-7 w-7 -translate-y-1/2 transform cursor-pointer items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-brand-light text-base shadow-navigation transition duration-300 hover:bg-brand hover:text-brand-light focus:outline-none md:h-8 md:w-8 lg:h-9 lg:w-9 lg:text-lg xl:h-10 xl:w-10 xl:text-xl"
          >
            {dir === 'rtl' ? <IoIosArrowBack /> : <IoIosArrowForward />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* End of product main slider */}

      <Scrollbar
        options={{
          overflow: { y: 'scroll' },
          scrollbars: {
            visibility: 'visible',
          },
        }}
      >
        <div className={`shrink-0 ${galleryClassName}`}>
          <Swiper
            id="productGalleryThumbs"
            modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
            onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
            spaceBetween={0}
            watchSlidesProgress
            freeMode
            observer
            observeParents
            breakpoints={galleryCarouselBreakpoints}
          >
            {gallery?.map((item) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                key={`product-thumb-gallery-${item.id}`}
                className="flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-center overflow-hidden rounded border border-border-base transition hover:opacity-75"
              >
                <Image
                  src={item?.thumbnail ?? productGalleryPlaceholder}
                  alt={`Product thumb gallery ${item.id}`}
                  // width={170}
                  // height={170}
                  width={70}
                  height={70}
                />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </Scrollbar>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThumbnailCarousel
```