# Swiper JS import CSS not working on Next 13

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, next.js13

I have this component where I am importing the required and modules from Swiper JS to the component. For some reason the files are not imported or working at all. This only happens when using Next 13. Is there something like a trick or workaround?

```
    "use client";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

// import required modules
import { Pagination } from "swiper";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Swiper
      pagination={{
        dynamicBullets: true,
      }}
      modules={[Pagination]}
      className="mySwiper"
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "swiper-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "swiper": "9.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this helping? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225146/swiperjs-styling-does-not-work-with-nextjs

Comment: Found that but it is a ugly way of working. It's basically importing everything even if you don't need other modules.

Comment: share which  Swiper js version you are using?

Comment: The latest version of Swiper JS. Just created a complete new clean Next 13 app and installed Swiper and imported everything from the demo and CSS is not imported or working.

Comment: "next" is "13.2.4," and "swiper" is "9.1.1." This is perfectly working fine with my project.

Comment: I have swiper at: "swiper": "^9.2.0", and Next "next": "13.3.0" I will try installing the versions you are using let's see.

Comment: @adnanjaved I have tried the versions you are using no luck at all. I have updated the code example. Mind checking or sharing how you did it?

Comment: I upgraded my nextjs and swiper versions according to yours and everything is working fine and no issue at all. 

I would like to suggest you to do one thing which might help you. Delete your node_modules folder and then reinstall all packages by 'npm/yarn install' command in your terminal/cmd.

Comment: Are you using "pages" instead of "app" structure? I reinstalled everything all node_modules older version and all latest still no luck. WORKS using "pages" it is a "app" issue.

Comment: I am using pages and NOT app structure.

Comment: @adnanjaved That's the problem there. When I use pages it works just fine. Must be a Next 13 issue. Thanks

Comment: @Galanthus
I discovered the solution. Try importing "swiper/swiper.min.css" instead of "swiper/css"; this works fine with the app structure.

Comment: @adnanjaved thank you friend. Yes this works but ruins the idea of only importing the CSS you need for a specific slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Try using CDN instead.

***Not using the experimental`/app` directory:***

Create a file called ***`_document.js`*** inside the ***`pages`*** folder. And then add swiperjs css CDN.

```js
// _document.js

import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

***Using The experimental `/app` directory:***

Edit the ***`app/layout.tsx`*** file (Note: it can be layout.js, layout.jsx, layout.ts, layout.tsx depending on your project)

```js
// app/layout.tsx

export default function RootLayout({
  // Layouts must accept a children prop.
  // This will be populated with nested layouts or pages
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
      </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

#### Method 2:

Try enabling ***`es-modules-support`*** in your Next.js project.

To do this:
Edit the ***`next.config.js`*** file. And put this:

```js
// next.config.js 

module.exports = {
  // Prefer loading of ES Modules over CommonJS
  experimental: { esmExternals: true },

  // other configuration here...
};
```

Comment: It works if I don't use the "app" folder structure. using "pages" instead works just fine.

Comment: This isn't for app folder this the solution i provided you is for regular nextjs. That we used to use before. `pages` or `src/pages` folder. But for tge experimental app folder this link tag will go to the layout file :)

Comment: Works using "pages" instead of "app" must be a next 13 bug.

Comment: @Galanthus I've updated the answer for the app directory please check it.

Comment: That seems to work. But the charm of using CSS import only where needed is gone now we have to use it globally. Hopefully Next 13 will solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try importing "swiper/swiper.min.css" instead of "swiper/css"; this works fine with the app structure.